# Add same class to multiple Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsplumb

I need to add a single class name to multiple objects using jQuery.

I'm aware of adding a class to multiple selectors like this:

```
$("#Div4 ,#Div5 ,#Div7 ,#Div8").addClass("something");
```

I tried the following code but it applies class only to the first object.

```
$(a[i].source, a[i].canvas, a[i].target).addClass("something");
```

In the above case, the classname `something` is applied only to `a[i].source`

Thoughts?

Comment: `$(a[i].source + ', ' + a[i].canvas + ', ' + a[i].target)`. `,` in your statement is treated as separator between parameters. Concatenate them using `+`.

Comment: @Tushar That only works if `a[i].source` and etc. actually returns a string that can be parsed as a selector. If it is a Node/Element, this will not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `a[i].source` and etc. actually references a Node/Element, you can use [`.add()` to add them individually to a collection](https://api.jquery.com/add/), i.e.:

```
$(a[i].source).add(a[i].canvas).add(a[i].target).addClass('something');
```

This can be unnecessarily verbose. You can simply construct an array and rely on implicit iteration in jQuery ([credit to @Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan)):

```
$([a[i].source, a[i].canvas, a[i].target]).addClass('something');
```

However, that's not really needed. What about just using native JS? [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) are very widely supported as of today:

**ES6:**

```
[a[i].source, a[i].canvas, a[i].target].forEach(el => el.classList.add('something'));
```

**ES5** (if you need backwards compatibility with *old* browsers that doesn't support ES6 syntax):

```
[a[i].source, a[i].canvas, a[i].target].forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.add('something');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to get them through id's add a default class to the elements you need to grab.

```
<div class="selectorClass"></div>
<span class="selectorClass"></span>
```

then 
using jquery

```
$(".selectorClass").addClass("something")
```